# background image won't show on tablet and mobile phone

Tags: css, mobile, sass, background-image, tablet

The background image shows perfectly on PC and simulator (tablet and phone), but it won't show on actual phone/tablet.

**code**

```
div#photo_break {
  @include viewport-unit(height, 28vw);
  background-image: url('<img>');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
  -moz-background-size: 100% auto;
  -o-background-size: 100% auto;
  background-position: center top;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

[website](http://www.fitnesscoachirina.com)

As you can see in this picture, in `Chromes simulator`the picture is shown.

[image: picture showing that in the Chrome simulator it works!]

The size of the image is not really large, or is it?

[image]

Comment: What kind of phone/tablet? If it’s iOS, it’s probably your background image’s dimensions that are the problem.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I tested it on iPad Air 2, iPhone 6s and Samsung S2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mobile`and `tablet browsers`do not support `background-attachment: fixed`.

changing this, solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Nice site. :D Let's try to solve your issue.

Make sure you do not have that CSS code inside any media query, since it might block that content.

You might also try to add a new media query with the same CSS you have just for mobile, like this `@media (min-width: 481px) { }`.

Clean your mobile browser's cache before loading the site again.

Answer (score 0):

Your background image is 12,000 pixels wide. It takes a long time to load to, I would suggest making the background of a parent div black inside the header, then putting an image in of just the person as the background of the element within that container if that makes sense. Save your mobile users data!

[image]

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, but the second image is the problem. There is a `div#photo_break`after the `services`part. The header photo runs perfectly